# OWIN startup file in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, namespaces, owin, startup

We currently have a website running on IIS on an in house server and using forms authentication, linked to the local AD server, to login staff so they can access the content management system.

We are in the process of moving over to Azure hosting and AD. Our current login method doesn't work in that environment so we need an alternative.

I've been experimenting with the example code provided in Azure AD and I got that working with authenticating a user.

The problem I currently have is that all of the examples are written in C#. All of our code is VB.

I've converted the code but I have now hit a few issues I cant work out.

The startup.vb file contains the following code

```
<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(ABC_Web_Auth.Startup))>
Namespace ABC_Web_Auth
    Public Class Startup
```

The web.config contains

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="ABC_Web_Auth.Startup, ABC_Web_Auth" />    
    <add key="owin:automaticAppStartup" value="false"/>
```

When I call

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(New AuthenticationProperties With {.RedirectUri = "/"}, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
```

I get the following error: 'No owin.Environment item was found in the context.'

Where do I save the startup.vb file? it's currently in App_code, is this correct?

This is running at website level, rather than as an application, so I'm assuming I have got namespace wrong in the owin:appstartup line.

Any help would be gratefully received